# How can we check extra parameter should be pass or not in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am new in writing ansible playbook. I am trying to find a way where I can ***check whether extra parameter passed or not***. If extra parameter is null or not passed with command line I want to output error message on console.

What I am trying here.

Run command:-

```
$ ansible-playbook mytasks.yml -e "action=del"
```

if `action` is null or not passed then it should display error message.

```
$ ansible-playbook mytasks.yml -e "action="  
$ ansible-playbook mytasks.yml
```

**mytasks.yml**

```
---
- hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true

tasks:
- shell: echo "I've got '{{ action }}' and am not afraid to use it!"
  when: action is defined

- fail: msg="Bailing out. this play requires 'action'"
  when: action is not defined
```

I am not getting any error message just get

```
TASK: [fail msg="Bailing out. this play requires {{action | mandatory}}"] *****
skipping: [localhost]
```

Please suggest me how can I check extra arguments is passed or not?

Comment: Any Suggestions or hint?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine one my machine. What Ansible version are you using ?

Comment: I am using ansible-1.4

Comment: Can you try with the latest anible and check if the problem still exist